# "0" is not convertible to BackgroundView in swift

Tags: swift, methods, ios8.1, class-method

I have this class method and i'm calling this method in my view controller

```
class func initWithNewFrame(var frame : CGRect?)
    {
        if let newFrame = frame
        {
            var backgroundView : BackgroundView = BackgroundView(frame: newFrame)

        }
    }
```

I,m calling as

```
var frameNew : CGRect = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x,
            self.view.frame.origin.y,
            self.view.frame.size.width,
            self.view.frame.size.height)
        self.gradientView = BackgroundView.initWithNewFrame(frameNew)
```

and i got this error "0" is not convertible to BackgroundView in swift
,
Please solve this and thanks in advance.

Comment: Add some frame values and call again

Comment: First thanks, I've already checked with the custom values but this problem occurs.

Comment: Is this the full definition of initWithNewFrame() method?

Comment: Yes, it is full implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reason:**

The error comes from here: `self.gradientView = BackgroundView.initWithNewFrame(frameNew)`

You assign `self.gradientView` with return value of `initWithNewFrame`, but in your code, `initWithNewFrame` has no return value.

In Swift, no return value means return an empty tuple. So you got "“0” is not convertible to BackgroundView" error, because you want to assign a `BackgroundView` with an empty tuple.

Maybe this is your expected method:

```
class func initWithNewFrame(var frame : CGRect?) -> BackgroundView? 
    {
        var backgroundView : BackgroundView? = nil
        if let newFrame = frame
        {
            backgroundView = BackgroundView(frame: newFrame)

        }
        return backgroundView
    }
```

**Update:**

if you want to make a custom initializer for class `BackgroundView`, try this:

```
convenience init(var frame : CGRect?) {
    if let newFrame = frame
    {
        self.init(newFrame )
    }
    // Do custom thing
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Boyi Li, i would try this one, but in my method i don't need return type if you can help me with that method.

Comment: Then you cannot assign the method return value to `self.gradientView`

Comment: What's your purpose of this statement `self.gradientView = BackgroundView.initWithNewFrame(frameNew)`?

Comment: Here i want to initialize my Background view frame.

Comment: Then you could call `self.gradientView = BackgroundView(frameNew)` directly

Comment: Thanks, Boyi ,Yes I know, but i just wanted to make initializer method for background view.

Comment: so you want to make another custom initializer for class `BackgroundView`?

Comment: Thanks all, Yes, but i don't know why i'm getting this weird error, for now i'm gonna change this method.

Comment: glad that I could help :)